# Rails server error on Rails 3, sqlite3 on development not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I have a rails test app set up, I want to just first get a page to show in the browser to see if I've gotten all the dependencies working.

I started the installation process on ubuntu from scratch, installed ruby, rails, sqlite3, mysql, and all the gem required as well. I'm using rails 3.0.7 and my app was created using

```
$ rails new test_app
```

And I wanted to run the server so I entered

```
$ rails server
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

I used

```
$ bundle install
```

to make sure after I googled it but nothing happened after this. any ideas on what's going on? Maybe I missed a step? Comment for any other details required.

**Edit:** here's the gemfile pastebin: http://pastebin.com/78dsGzVx I also ran bundle install after uncommenting the following:

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: is sqlite listed when you run 'bundle list'? Can you post the entry from your gemfile

Comment: gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'.just give it a try..Also it would be nice if u post your gemfile

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `gem "sqlite3"` to the Gemfile and then run `bundle install`

Comment: btw: is it supposed to fetch from the web everytime? or can i somehow cache/store bundle install files locally for development?

Comment: you can allways set source for all your gems or just a particular gem you need with `source` option

Answer (score 1):

There is written `Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.` It means you should add:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to your `Gemfile` and then run `bundle` again.

Also it can be useful, if you haven't got sqlite installed:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

Also make sure to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev sqlite3
```